# how to take the average of grades of a student class in student.py

Tags: python, list, oop

I have a python `class` called student that includes variables and methods.

Each student has a name, age, and a list of grades.

I have a method `AVGofGrades()` that takes the list of grades and returns the average.

I do not know how to create a function that will take this list of grades from the student object and loop through it to return the avgerage.

So far I have this:

```
class student():
    def __init__(self,name,age, *grades):
        self.stdName=name
        self.stdAge = age
        self.stdGrade = grades


    def getName(self):
        return self.stdName

    def setName(self,Name):
        self.stdName = Name


    def getAge(self):
        return self.stdAge

    def setAge(self, Age):
        self.stdAge = Age

    def getGrade(self):

        gradeLevel = None

        if AVGofGrades(self.stdGrade) >=20:
            gradeLevel =  "A"
        elif self.stdGrade >=18:
            gradeLevel =  "B"
        elif self.stdGrade >=15:
            gradeLevel = "C"
        else:
            gradeLevel = "F"

        print("the student {0}, have a grade {1}".format(self.stdName, gradeLevel))

    def setGrade(self,*Grades):
        self.stdGrade = Grades

    def AVGofGrades(self, *student):
        result = 0
        for i in student:
            student[2]



std1 = student("georges", 17, 80,23,50,34,80,78)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have grades already in `self.stdGrade`

So, you don't need to pass anything in the method `AVGofGrades`, as you are providing all the arguments needed when you create the Student Object.

Your `AVGofGrades` can be as below:

```
def AVGofGrades(self):
    return sum(self.stdGrade)/len(self.stdGrade)
```

You can now create an instance of the class and get the AVGofGrades as below:

```
std1 = Student("georges", 17, 80,23,50,34,80,78)
print(std1.AVGofGrades())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple math expression:

```
    def AVGofGrades(self, *student):
        return sum(student) / len(student)
```

You should call it as `self.AVGofGrades()` though, not just `AVGofGrades()`.

Comment: the * student includes name, age, list of grades where first 2 argument are the name and the age **the third will be the list of grades**

Comment: Not in `if AVGofGrades(self.stdGrade) >=20:`, in that call only the grades are passed. To skip the first two arguments use `return sum(student[2:]) / len(student[2:])`.